# Regex: how to remove inital and final quotes from lines

Tags: regex, perl

I would like you to ask for help in creation regex.
I have something like notepad++ and I have only one field to put regex /this software uses perl to parse/ so I can not use the programming language.
Regex should match quotes on beginning and end of the line /sometimes with semicolon after final quote/ but without content because I'm using it to remove mentioned quotes.

Input data:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
"Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing "elit."
```

Expected result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
"Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing "elit"
```

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: so `"Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.` should give `Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.`?

Comment: nope, all quotes inside line should be save. 
Sorry for the inaccurate explanation

Comment: This looks like an [`XY problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you expand a bit on the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what output you want to generate for each line of the example data.

Comment: Sorry for that. 

I have file with data /example above/. I have to go line by line with regex. It should remove all quotes on beginning and end /with semicolon sometimes/ of the line but only in this case "content";

Comment: Yes all inside should be save. So lines from my example - line 3 and 4 should be untouched.

Comment: There's no way to do that without diving to something from far more complicated. Consider this case: `"Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing "elit"`: I don't think you want this kind of result: `Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing "elit`?

Comment: You have right, I don't want but I can agree with that. Something is better that nothing. If regex will work for three lines as I expected and for one of them not, it is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$s = $1 if $s =~ /^"([^"]*)";$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
^"(.+)";?$
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Db3GhQ/1) (and mind the modifiers!).

Comment: Yep it will match but whole line, I need to match this kind of line but only quotes. If will be possible to use lookahead for this (.+) to take out match.

Answer (score 0):

```
my (undef, $result) = $input =~ /^("?)(.+?)\1;?$/;
```

When the line begins with a quote and ends with a quote (plus-or-minus a semi-colon), the data inside the quotes is captured.
If a quote doesn't appear at both the beginning and the end of the line, then any other quotes are included in the result.

The payload is in the second captured group, so you want to ignore the first result (or take `$2` after running the pattern match).

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^("?)(.+?)\1;?$/) {
        print $2;
    } else {
        print "No match: $_";
    }
}
__DATA__
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
"Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
"Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: Good idea but I'm able only to put regex.
Basically it should works in notepad++, just only regex. I know that it complicated a lot.

Comment: @Martin I don't understand your comment. `/^("?)(.+?)\1;?$/` is a regex.

Comment: To "remove content", `s/^("?)(.+?)\1;?$/$2/` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean all of the line, *except* completely surrounding quotes.

Backreferences are the key here. Using a character class, you can even use both single and double quotes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = <<'DATA';
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
"Lorem" ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.
DATA

for ( split /^/, $data ) {
    printf '->%s<-'.$/, $2 if /^(["']?)(.*)\g1;?$/;
}
```

The last example with your updated question doesn't work with this solution.